# Split a pandas dataframe into train and test. Then convert into pivot while having same row names(strings) and column names (strings)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Below is the sample dataset:

```
| * |reviewerID     |asin       |overall|
|---|---------------| --------- | ----- |
|0  |A2HD75EMZR8QLN |0700099867 |1.0    |
|1  |A3UR8NLLY1ZHCX |0700099867 |4.0    |
|2  |A1INA0F5CWW3J4 |0700099867 |1.0    |
|3  |A1DLMTOTHQ4AST |0700099867 |3.0    |
|4  |A361M14PU2GUEG |0700099867 |4.0    |
```

from [here](https://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/).

I need to split this into test train parts and convert them into tables having *reviewerID* as row-names and *asin* as column-names. Also it has be ensured that both of them have same set of reviewerIDs (split using stratify on *reviewerID*) and also they need to have same table row names and column names.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use **train_test_split** of **sklearn**:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = pd.read_csv(r"\Dataset\pump_sensor_data\sensor.csv")
X_df_train, X_df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
```